# Dificuldade em colocar zeros não significativos num número binário convertido

Tags: c

Encontrei um código na web que converte decimais para binários (32 bits), porém eu necessitava de um de (256 bits) por isso alterei o código da maneira que achei estar correta, porém após o determinado tamanho os zeros não significativos são adicionados da maneira correta...

```
int main() {
    unsigned long long int n = 140735601943344; // Número de entrada
    unsigned long long int r; // Resultado do deslocamento
    int i; // Contador

    // Lê o número
    //printf("Digite o numero: ");
    //scanf("%llu", &n);

    printf("\nNumero convertido para 256 com os 0 nao significativos:\n");
    // Utiliza um número de 256 bits como base para a conversão.
    for(i = 255; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Executa a operação shift right até a 
    // última posição da direita para cada bit.
        r = n >> i;

    // Por meio do "e" lógico ele compara se o valor 
    // na posição mais à direita é 1 ou 0 
    // e imprime na tela até reproduzir o número binário.
        if(r & 1) {
            printf("1");
        } else {
            printf("0");
        }
    } 
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nNumero convertido: 140735601943344\n");
    printf("\n11111111111111110001111100011111010001100110000\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Nessa imagem é o limite de zeros sigficados corretos, no código seria i = 67...

[image: Nessa imagem é o limite de zeros sigficados corretos, no código seria i = 67]

Aqui é a execução que eu precisava... Porém, como podem ver, com o i > 67 (255, no caso) surgem uns "1" que não fazem sentido...

[image: Aqui é a execução que eu precisava... Porém, como podem ver, com o i > 67 (255, no caso) surgem uns "1" que não fazem sentido]

Qual o problema com o código?

Comment: Desculpem... O código é na linguagem C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O operador *shift* tem um limite máximo que dependende da plataforma/compilador.

Se você estiver utilizando o [gcc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Shifting) em uma plataforma PC 64 bits, por exemplo, e ultrapassar 64 o comportamento desse operador é indefinido.

Uma solução possível (e simples) para o caso de conversão para mais de 64 bits, é criar um buffer para armazenar o resultado e dividir o número por 2 sucessivamente para obter os bits. Quando a divisão chegar a zero, as próximas divisões sempre retornarão o bit zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  unsigned long long int n = 140735601943344; // Número de entrada
  char buffer[257]; // Buffer para armazenar o resultado
  int i; // Contador

  buffer[256] = '\0'; // "zera" o último caracter do buffer
  printf("\nNumero convertido para 256 com os 0 nao significativos:\n");

  // Utiliza um número de 256 bits como base para a conversão.
  for(i = 255; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    // Por meio do "e" lógico ele compara se o valor 
    // na posição mais à direita é 1 ou 0 
    // e guarda o dígito binário no buffer.
    if(n & 1)
    {
      buffer[i] = '1';
    } else {
      buffer[i] = '0';
    }
    // Divide o número por 2 para obter o próximo bit
    n /= 2; 
  }
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\nNumero convertido: 140735601943344\n");
  printf("\n11111111111111110001111100011111010001100110000\n");

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Após a execução (truncado, para facilitar a visualização):

```
Numero convertido para 256 com os 0 nao significativos:
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000011111111111111110001111100011111010001100110000


Numero convertido: 140735601943344

11111111111111110001111100011111010001100110000
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Existem outras formas de fazer esta implementação e, caso o operador não ultrapasse a largura de bits do dado, a versão com o operador *shift* tem um desempenho muito melhor.